# Rename [star-wars-tor] → [star-wars-old-republic]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I'm playing around with Google searches, and it looks like we're at a big disadvantage due to our SWTOR tag being [star-wars-tor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-tor).  It seems like people will either be searching "SWTOR" or some variant of the full name with "Old Republic" being the most important bit, and we don't match on either of those.  Google seems to recognize "SWTOR" as an acronym for Star Wars The Old Republic (huh, didn't know they did that), so if we can get most of the name in there I think we'll be okay.

So, unless anyone strongly objects, I'd like to rename the tag to [star-wars-old-republic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-old-republic).

Comment: I, who mistakenly tagged a SWTOR game "the old republic" because I *thought* that's what the tag was, heartily endorse this message.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

I've already just done so, so you can't do it too!

Comment: I blame Powerlord

Comment: Heh. -1, pointless?

Comment: @NickT No, "I've done so" answers are not pointless. Without such an (upvoted) answer Community will think this question is unanswered and bump it up periodically

Comment: +1 for getting the job done.

Answer (score 2):

The main tag should obviously be [swtor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor).  I'm not just saying that because I made it either.

Think from a googler's point of view: "swtor classes", "swtor story quests", "swtor companion list".  They aren't going to type "star wars" - it's too long.  "old republic" is right out.  I actually had trouble typing "old republic" just now.  There - that's twice, no more.

---

Self Kudos, lol: [Rename [star-wars-old republic] → [swtor]?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/rename-star-wars-old-republic-swtor)

Comment: If I were to google I'd type "the old republic". Keep in mind Google does autosuggestions: you don't _have_ to type in every letter. Google already knows what you're talking about at "the ol".

Comment: You may be right, but I'm hoping Google is smart enough to identify "Star Wars Old Republic" as SWTOR.  Try searching "swtor" now: it shows results for "Star Wars: The Old Republic"

Comment: -1, Google is smart and rapidly equates acronyms with the full, expanded form (as David mentions).  No need to perpetuate such ugliness.

Comment: Yeah, game name abbreviation is just not how we've been rolling so far.

Comment: [This isn't the solution we're looking for.  You can go about your business.  Move along… move along!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/quotes?qt=qt0440731)

Comment: I used to make funny comments on posts like you... then I took an arrow in the knee!