# Rename [swtor] → [star-wars-the-old-republic]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

Back in 2011, this site had a tag of [star-wars-old-republic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-old-republic), since adding "the" increased the character count beyond the 25 character limit.

Then we had [Rename [star-wars-tor] → [star-wars-old-republic]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3552/47878), since this didn't match any search terms online. This was implemented.

A day later, we had [Rename [star-wars-old republic] → [swtor]?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3574/47878) because Google's alogorithms weren't finding any pages for the previous tag name. This was also implemented.

The second link says this:

> Apparently Google's acronym expansion of SWTOR → Star Wars: The Old Republic only works on exact matches, so our "star wars old republic" fails to match that.

Now that we have a 35 character limit, could we rename the tag to [star-wars-the-old-republic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-old-republic), using the full name of the game (including "the")?

This tag rename should satisfy Google's algorithm. As I understand it, that should satisfy Google's algorithms, even if people search for `swtor classes` or whatever because Google's acronym expansion will include results tagged with the full name of the game.

This would also make it more consistent be consistent with other Star Wars tags we have on the site, like [star-wars-jedi-knight](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-jedi-knight), [star-wars-empire-at-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-empire-at-war), [star-wars-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2015), etc.

Can this be done? Of course, I think that keeping [swtor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor) as a tag synonym would be desirable.

Comment: It's worth noting the previous Old Republic games, [tag:star-wars-kotor] and [tag:star-wars-kotor-2], have full titles longer than 35 characters.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yeah, I noticed that we unfortunately can't rename those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now done:

- [swtor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swtor)  → [star-wars-the-old-republic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-old-republic)

It might be worth reviewing the [current synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/star-wars-the-old-republic/synonyms) of the tag and seeing if they are still relevant to the expanded tag.